# Java : Any way to save a string input into pdf

Tags: java, pdf, actionlistener, jtextfield

So I have to take a string input from GUI using `Textfield` and make it show up in a pdf document, when I use `ActionListener` :

```
b1[0].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
{
    s=tf1[0].getText();
}
});
```

When I run the gui and type in the tf1 and press b1, it should save it in s right? But it isn't doing that, however if I just hardcode `s="string"` it shows up in the pdf. Any ideas?

Forgot to mention I am using iText so the only problem i am having is that the `String` s is not getting saved from the `TextField`

Also the code for the `actionlistener` class if you want it:

```
public class GUI {
public  static String s;
public static void  gui(){

    {   
        try{
        String File_Name="C:/Users/Ray/Desktop/test.txt";
        ReadFile rf=new ReadFile(File_Name);
        JFrame f1=new JFrame("Maintest");
        JPanel p1=new JPanel();
        JPanel p2=new JPanel();
        final String[] aryLines=rf.OpenFile();
        final JTextField tf1[]=new JTextField[22];
        JButton []b1=new JButton[6];
        String bNames="OK";
        final JTextField tf2[]=new JTextField[aryLines.length];
        f1.setSize(200,450);


        JLabel l1[]=new JLabel[20];

        for ( int i=0; i < aryLines.length; i++ )
        {
            b1[i]=new JButton(bNames);
            l1[i]=new JLabel("Enter Serial# for "+ aryLines[i]);

            p1.add(l1[i]);p1.add(tf1[i] = new JTextField());p1.add(b1[i]);
        }


            p1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p1,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

            f1.add(p1,BorderLayout.WEST);



                b1[0].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
                {
                    s=""+tf1[0].getText();
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
                });

            f1.show();
        }

            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.print(e);
            }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: are you experiencing any problems? can you use external libraries as [itext](http://itextpdf.com/)?

Comment: try debugging and see if tf1[0].getText() actually gets the data from Textfield.

Comment: This may help you : http://howtodoinjava.com/apache-commons/create-pdf-files-in-java-itext-tutorial/

Comment: @Jordi Castilla Forgot to mention i am using iText so the only problem i am having is that the string s is not getting saved from the textfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry that I can't answer in more detail, but you could check if the `tf1[0].getText()` works. Just put a `System.out.println("Text: "tf1[0].getText());` into your `ActionListener`. I'm pretty sure it will be null or "Text: ". For further help you'll have to provide more code.

[Please take a look at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i added that, and then added "haha"  in the gui textfield , the output was Text:haha, so i guess that it is taking input, but why isn't it then saving that in s

Comment: That's really strange. Maybe try it with String.valueOf(tf1[0].getText()). Could you please provide more code? Also add the valueOf to the System.out.println().

Comment: Tried what you suggested, same output as before

Comment: Okay, the only thing wich seems a bit odd to me is the static declaration of your String s. Logically that shouldn't cause the problem, but maybe you should try to make it a non-static variable. If you need it to be static, call it with GUI.s. Sorry I don't have any other suggestions.

Comment: I've tried to declare it inside the gui and it worked, so i don't really know why it wont work from `actionlistener`